# how to find the text is entered by keyboard or barcode scanner in windows application

Tags: vb.net-2010, barcode-scanner, windows

I am developing a windows application. the user must enter the text by keyboard or use barcode scanner to enter the text simultaneously. I want to find the input is entered by keyboard or entered by barcode scanner. if the input is enter by the keyboard i want to implement logic A otherwise if input is entered by barcode scanner, i want to implement logic B. Can someone help me please.

this is code i am using

```
  Private Sub FrmLogin_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TxtAxleNumber.KeyDown
    Dim finalText As String = ""
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Txtbox1.Text = finalText
        finalText = ""
    Else
        finalText += GetAsciiCharacter(e.KeyCode).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

I am using form keydown event while the user scans the input through barcode scanner, i will get the keycode  and find the character of the keycode and assign the value to the textbox.

My requirement is i want to find the text is entered by keyboard or barcode scanner.

Thanks in regards.

Comment: You can use a flag and set it when you are assigning value from barcode scanner to the text property of text box. And check that flag value to decide if logic a or logic b should be used.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how should we find the entered text is written return by keyboard or barcode scanner

Comment: Do you have a code which assigns value from barcode scanner to textbox? Also share the code where you want todecide if text is entered by keyboard or scanner

Comment: yes @ChetanRanpariya. i will edit the post and update my code in few minutes

Comment: The same gets executed when you scan the barcode using barcode scanner?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the same gets executed right. but is possible to check in the keypress event the key is raised by barcode scanner or keyboard.

Comment: How a barcode scanner can raise keydown event?

Comment: definitely barcode sanner rasing the keydown event.

Comment: I am not sure how you have implemented this.. but when the barcode scanner invokes the event you can set some flag value (like isFromBarcode) to true and later you check what is the value of of this flag to decide if the value is entered by barcode or manually.